# Field 'dependencyGraphManifests' doesn't exist on type 'Repository'

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I am trying to make a react project which can fetch data from a github repo and list all the project dependencies, their current version in the project, latest version available, outdated or not and whether vulnerable. I am trying to use the github graphQL to fetch data but keeps on throwing this error.

> Field 'dependencyGraphManifests' doesn't exist on type 'Repository'

. Can anyone help me with this? How can I get these data from github? Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Read https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/schema-previews#access-to-a-repositories-dependency-graph-preview.

If you set the following header it will be there:

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.hawkgirl-preview+json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gh api -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.hawkgirl-preview+json' graphql 
--paginate -f query='query {
     repository(owner:"octocat",name:"Hello-World") {
     dependencyGraphManifests {
     totalCount
     nodes {
      filename
    }
  edges {
    node {
      blobPath
      dependencies {
        totalCount
        nodes {
              packageName
              requirements
              hasDependencies
              packageManager
           }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).